# MVC area separate membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I have no idea how can I resolve that problem. In a nutshell - I want to have separate membership in one of my area in application project. But this "separated" membership have to use the same database as "main" membership.

In my main project I use `SimpleMembershipProvider`.

Example:

When "normal" user loggin on http://example.com I can get information about him with `HttpContext.User.Identity` in all of controllers and views in main project - he is just logged. But when he enter `special` area (http://example.com/special), `HttpContext.User.Identity` have to returns null in that area - user is "unlogged".

On the other hand, when "special" user entered http://example.com/special and successfully loggin in - he is authorized on all `special` area, excluding main application (only at that area). At main project he is "unlogged" - he have to log in (with user who has "normal" role).

How can I achieve this without headaches?

Comment: Use Roles! Have a role for each area, then on each controller of those areas have `[Authorize(Roles="ThisArea")]`, it would be the way I would go about doing it! Then you can create a few custom attributes and filters!

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the textbook use case for Role based security.

You assign a role to a user and grant access to an area based on membership in that role.  So, you would create an Administrator role, and only grant users with the Administrator role access to the Administrator section.  This can be done easily with the `[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")] attribute.

You can also use roles in your application to define which fields they see, or which fields they can edit.  You would add code to check for access to a role via `User.IsInRole("Administrators")` and add conditional logic around your edit or view fields.